# WPF threading error(Invalid Operation Exception was handled)

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, visual-studio-2010

I am creating WPF Project and I have two screen

1)Loading Screen

2)MainWindow

My code is as follows from Loading screen

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        loadingThread = new Thread(load);
        loadingThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        loadingThread.Start();

    }

   private void load()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(showDelegate, "Loading UI...");
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        //do some loading work
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(hideDelegate);

        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        (Action)delegate() { this.CLose(); });

        MainWindow Mw = new MainWindow();//Gives me the error
        Mw.ShowDialog();
    }
```

When I call my Mainwindow screen I get error "**The Application object is being shut down**".I beleive since the thread is being closed I am getting the error ,
can anyone tell me what would be the other possible ways to call my main window

Thank You All

Comment: Perhaps because you close the last window before creating a new one.

Comment: Yes but where should I call my MainWindow then..thats my question

Comment: Before the invoke of `this.Close`

Comment: @Silvermind No it does not work whole application closes I added the code before this.Dispatvher.invoke

Comment: @AlexFarber Because I want to exit the loading screen and switch to main screen

Comment: You can control shutdown application with Application.Current.ShutdownMode - OnMainWindowClose, OnLastWindowClose and OnExplicitShutdown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're closing the last window which invokes the shutdown command for the application.
Create and open the new window before you close 'this' window:

You could change this:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
    (Action)delegate() { this.Close(); });
```

to this:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
(Action)delegate() 
{
    MainWindow Mw = new MainWindow();
    // Mw.ShowDialog(); I changed this line because it cannot be a dialog here.
    Mw.Show();
    this.Close();
});
```

Comment: You can control shutdown application with Application.Current.ShutdownMode - OnMainWindowClose, OnLastWindowClose and OnExplicitShutdown.

Comment: @misak, altough that might be an option, it was unneccesary because the OP wanted to create a new window anyway. Setting it to explicit could have been an option, but that would mean you need to also explicitly _do so_ anywhere. This way it keeps the default behaviour.